# $_GET variable with messed up encoding

Tags: php, encoding

I'm having a great deal of trouble with encoding in my site.

This is my problem right now, if I go to `analize.php?dialog=árbol` which code is:

```
<?
echo $_GET['dialog'];
echo "sabía";
```

on it I get:

```
sabÃ­a
sabía
```

I'm using ANSI, changing to UTF-8 breaks both. I don't understand why this happens, also there isn't any code above this. I don't care about how they display since this file is only used to fetch data from my database. But I need to make `$_GET` display properly so I can include it on the query.

How can this be done?

Comment: http://pokit.org/get/7570f6e4406588d65f28ffb3c50c4224.png

Comment: What encoding is your source code saved as? What encoding are you interpreting/serving the file as?

Comment: Have you tried utf_encode() and utf8_decode(). Sounds like you have, but just making sure

Comment: @Liso22, I'd recommend you take a look at this: http://kunststube.net/encoding/

Comment: I'm saving the file in ANSI, saving it in UTF-8 doesn't fix anything.

Comment: @Liso22 do you have this in your markup: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` ?

Comment: Am I missing something?  Shouldn't $_GET['display'] result in "árbol"?  You'll run into problems comparing multi-byte strings.  Do you know if the mb_string extension is enabled?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot send the character "í" in a URL, URLs must use a subset of the ASCII charset. Therefore the URL is encoded to `?dialog=sab%C3%ADa` by your browser before being sent to the server. `%C3%AD` represents the two bytes `C3 AD`, which is the UTF-8 encoding for the character "í". You can confirm this with `var_dump($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);`. This is automatically decoded by PHP, the result is the UTF-8 byte sequence for "sabía" with the "í" being encoded using the two bytes `C3 AD`.

Your browser is interpreting this byte sequence using the Windows-1252 or ISO-8859-1 charset. The byte `C3` represents "Ã" in this encoding, the byte `AD` represents a soft-hyphen and is invisible.

Two possible solutions:

1. use UTF-8 everywhere (recommended!)

   - save your source code as UTF-8
   - output a header that forces the browser to interpret the site as UTF-8:

     ```
     header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
     ```
2. convert the `$_GET` values to Windows-1252/ISO-8859-1 (or whatever encoding you want  to use on your site) using `mb_convert_encoding` or `iconv` (not recommended)

   - even in this case you should set a header that announces to the browser what encoding exactly you're using

In short, you need to make sure you're using the same encoding everywhere and specify to the browser what encoding exactly that is.

Comment: Well put. I just finished your article about _encodings_. An excellent read! +1