# # in query string breaks php GET

Tags: php, get, query-string

Running into a problem with a form I have built. A user typed in a hash (#) for their address in the address field. When their address is put into a query string after the form is submitted all of my GET variables are broke after the field with the #. Anyone know why this would happen? Do I need to convert the # to a different character or use some other type of encoding? This is the code I have on the page that grabs the values from the query string..

```
<?php echo $_GET["address"]; ?><br/> // if this field has a # in the value, the GET variables below do not work..
<?php echo $_GET["city"]; ?><br/>
<?php echo $_GET["state"]; ?>
```

Comment: [Somewhat related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528925/get-variable-with-messed-up-encoding)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `#` is a valid anchor symbol in URL and only has meaning to the client browser.

In all likelihood you should probably be using a POST for this form rather than a GET, at which point this issue goes away.

Usually a good rule of thumb is to use URL parameters (GET) for cases where you want the URL to be navigable by any user and where such navigation will not change any data on the server (or do things like trigger emails, etc.).  A good example of this might be the use of product ID's in the URL for a e-commerce catalog application to determine what product to show on a page.

You should typically use POST for cases where you are going to change data on the server or trigger some action which basic navigation to a page should not trigger. Building on the earlier example of an e-commerce app, you might typically use POST to add an item to a users shopping cart.

Answer (score 0):

get parameter should be url endcoded http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php another option would be to build your query string with http_build_query (http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

Answer (score -1):

The hash in a url is a document fragment and read by the browser. Hence anything after the hash sign in a url will not be transferred to the server as a query. You need to URL encode the hash (by javascript i presume). See :http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp