# Incorrect polish letters in $_GET

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding, get, polish

I'm sending some polish names via $_GET, and when I'm trying to var dump it, I'm getting sth like:

```
A?a
```

which should be:

```
Ała
```

In url it looks like:

A%B3

I've set ehaders to utf-8, ant still it doesnt work. How can I solve this?

EDIT: it looks like problem starts from getting this text from database. It looks like it should in table, but when rying to SELECT it and echo - the problem starts

Comment: @up nope - I'm NOT talking about databases at all. Only, simple $_GET

Comment: I'm reading, and sadly there's nothing I've not tried

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528925/get-variable-with-messed-up-encoding

Comment: please check edit